# Changing the place of the subject at the end with all verbs (is it possible?)

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I know that when it comes to dialogue writing, we can change the subject of the sentence at the end, for example:

"Hello," **said John.**

"Hi there," **replied Mary.**

"How are you?" **asked John.**

"I'm OK," **responded Mary.**

And so on.

But can we do that with every single verb? For example:

"Stop right now!" **ordered the father.**

"It's a good song," **recognized the girl.**

"He'll be here tomorrow," **guaranteed Thomas.**

"I'll be all right," **promised the boy.**

In these sentences, is it understandable that the noun at the end is the subject and not the direct object of the sentence? Or is it confusing for a native reader of English?

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: 'Recognize' is at best a very unusual quotative verb; can you find a supporting reference (rather than a few examples on the internet)? The rest of your examples are fine with or without inversion after the quote (though I'd say inversion is usual with 'say').

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's perfectly normal word order with quoted speech, regardless of the verb. Here's a rather technical article all about the order of the portions of a sentence that reports speech: http://journals.openedition.org/erea/3406. It mostly uses forms of "say" in its examples, but it shows uses of alternatives as well.